# Remove values that appear only once in a DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, dataframe

I have a dataframe with different values in column `x`. I want to drop values that appear only once in a column.

So this:

```
   x
1 10
2 30
3 30
4 40
5 40
6 50
```

Should turn into this:

```
   x
2 30
3 30
4 40
5 40
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do that.

Comment: Do you want to drop the entire row or replace the value with NaN?

Comment: Checkout: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html

Comment: @rurp I want to drop the entire row, but replace the value with NaN also help me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can easily get this by using [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) and [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) :

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([10, 30, 30, 40, 40, 50], columns=['x'])

In [3]: df = df[df.groupby('x').x.transform(len) > 1]

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
    x
1  30
2  30
3  40
4  40
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) and then [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) it:

```
In [9]:    
df = pd.DataFrame([10, 30, 30, 40, 40, 50], columns=['x'])
df = df.groupby('x').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
df

Out[9]:
    x
1  30
2  30
3  40
4  40
```

Answer (score 6):

How about a more explicit way to keep all duplicated values:

```
df = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset='x', keep=False), :]
```

Conversely, to keep only unique values:

```
df = df.loc[~df.duplicated(subset='x', keep=False), :]
```

And this:

```
df = df.loc[~df.duplicated(subset='x'), :]
```

is equivalent to:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='x')
```

Comment: This is much faster than the accepted answer.