# Boolean Logic Inside Pandas Query Statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have the following dataframe, `ds`, that was arrived at by means of `.merge`:

```
            Date_x  Invoice_x         Name Coupon_x Location_x        Date_y  \
1   2017-12-24   700349.0     John Doe     NONE      VAGG1   2017-12-24
2   2017-12-24   700349.0     John Doe     NONE      VAGG1   2017-12-24
4          NaN        NaN  Sue Simpson      NaN        NaN   2017-12-23

   Invoice_y  Price  Coupon_y  Location_y
1     800345  17.95   CHANGE    VAGG1
2     800342   9.95   GADSLR    VAGG1
4     800329  34.95   GADSLR    GG2
```

What I am looking for is an output of:

```
         Date  Invoice      Name Coupon Location  Price
1  2017-12-24   700349  John Doe   NONE    VAGG1  17.95
2  2017-12-24   700349  John Doe   NONE    VAGG1   9.95
```

By use of the following code:

```
ds = ds.query('Price_x != Price_y')
```

I get

```
        Date_x  Invoice_x         Name  Price_x Coupon_x Location_x  \
1   2017-12-24   700349.0     John Doe    59.95     NONE      VAGG1
2   2017-12-24   700349.0     John Doe    59.95     NONE      VAGG1
4          NaN        NaN  Sue Simpson      NaN      NaN        NaN

         Date_y  Invoice_y  Price_y  Coupon_y  Location_y
1   2017-12-24      800345    17.95   CHANGE    VAGG1
2   2017-12-24      800342     9.95   GADSLR    VAGG1
4   2017-12-23      800329    34.95   GADSLR    GG2
```

Which is close to what I want. The extra columns can be removed by `.drop` and `.rename`. What is really missing is the ability to get rid of rows where the name only occurs one.

I have been trying logic along the following lines in the query statement:

```
 ds =ds.query('Price_x != Price_y & Name > 1')
```

Which results in the following error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

EDIT:

```
ds = ds[(ds[Price_x] != ds[Price_y])  &  (ds['Name'].value_counts() > 1)]
```

Which results in:

```
NameError: name 'Price_x' is not defined
```

Alternatively, trying:

```
ds = ds[(ds.Price_x != ds.Price_y)  &  (ds['Name'].value_counts() > 1)]
```

results in

```
c:\users\...\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3140: RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
  return this.join(other, how=how, return_indexers=return_indexers)
C:\Users\...\Python\Python36\Scripts\ipython:1: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
```

As well as `ds` being empty.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date_x, Invoice_x, Name, Price_x, Coupon_x, Location_x, Date_y, Invoice_y, Price_y, Coupon_y, Location_y]
Index: []
```

Comment: What is your desired output? What do you mean when you say "get rid of rows where the name only occurs one."?

Comment: `df.query("...").groupby(by=[...]).filter(lambda g: g.shape[0] > 1)`

Comment: @jakevdp I express what I am looking for in my second code block. 'What I am looking for is an output of'

Comment: @PaulH Any chance you could post the full line as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ds = ds[ds.groupby('Name').Name.transform(len) > 1]
ds = ds.query('Price_x != Price_y')
```

The first line drops the names that appear only once. See this [Remove values that appear only once in a DataFrame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071182/remove-values-that-appear-only-once-in-a-dataframe-column) for more information.

Also, in your error df[Price_x] -> it should be df["Price_x"]. One would either do df.Price_x or df["Price_x"].

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with multiple steps: first use `pd.value_counts` to count the number of occurances of each name, then join that to the original data and query on that. For example:

```
counts = pd.value_counts(ds.Name).reset_index()
counts.columns = ['Name', 'Name_count']
ds.merge(counts, on='Name').query('Price_x != Price_y & Name_count > 1')
```